# Android create layout folder based on same screen density

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-screen-support

I need to create two different layout folders based on this http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytabs/specs.html specifications.

But I've seen that the two devices has the same display resolution and only difference is the size of the screen.

Is there a way to distinguish the two res folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912190/screen-support-multiple-devices-using-layout-large-layout-normal-and-layout-xlar

Answer (score 0):

on Android you can specify smallest width on the resources. Examples:

- layout-sw600dp/  < that's a 7" like the Nexus 7
- layout-sw720dp/  < that's a 10" like the Nexus 10

so all you have to do is to find out what's the smallest width in DP for the 8.4 inches (probably something around 660dp) and create the resource folder for it.

You can run this app on the tab 8.4 to find out it's size: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.qbus.sizemeup

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I do not have the tablet... but if the device has the same display resolution (but different ppi), how can I create folder with sw<N>dp template?

Comment: You have to do the math using screen PPI and resolution in pixels to find the screen width and height in DP. Then use the smallest of the two as your identifier. You probably can Google to find an online calculator for that.